# How to get selected checkbox row serial number values in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which shows bill details. when clicking on the checkbox the value will sum. along that I need to get the bill id number which is checked and display it in the input field separated by comma

```js
var sum = 0;
     $('body').on('click', '.due-fee', function() {
     var status = '';
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      sum += parseInt($(this).val());
      status = 'Paid';
      } else {
      sum -= parseInt($(this).val());
      status = 'Not paid';
      }
      $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).find('td:eq(2)').text(status);
      $('#msg').text(sum);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name=form1 action="GET">
    <table class='table table-striped' >
    <tr > <th >Bill id</th><th >FEES name</th><th >status</th></tr>
    <tr ><td>1</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=100;> fee = 100 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=200 ;> fee = 200 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
    <tr  ><td>3</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=300;> fee = 300 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
    <tr ><td>4</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=400 ;> fee = 400 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>

    </table>
    <input type="text" name="bill_id" id="bill_id">
 <input type="submit" >
    </form>

    <br>
    
    <div id=msg></div>
```

for example

i select 2 and 4

expected output :
selected bill id= 2,4
sum=600

Comment: Your question only contains a bunch of _"I need"_ and not enough _"I've tried x and y happened while expecting z"_. Please update your question to be clearer and to include your complete attempt, expected results from that attempt and what results your getting. Also, what does the posted code have to do with PHP and MySQL?

Comment: I am sorry this actually small part of my code which I code in PHP. the table data are from the database. and and the Get form is received by php code and update using sql. and iam sorry to tag which i don't show here

Comment: I tryed a code it not working thats y i post a working code

Comment: and please understand by saying "i need" I mean my requirement

Comment: I understand why you mean, but a question must include a proper description what the current issue actually is. What happens when you run the code you've posted? Where _exactly_ are you stuck?

Comment: That's why i posted a snippet. I am unable to get the value of bill id. I am able to get a single value in the text box(Current Selection). but I am unable get multiple selected value

Answer (score 1):

You have write script code before including js library, so this was not working. 
Please try this because it will solve the problem of showing the sum amount in the imput box and when you will submit the form it will have all the values in the query string as you want .

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var sum = 0;
     $(document).on('click', '.due-fee', function() {

     var status = '';
     var id_string = '';

      id =  $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).find('td:eq(0)').text();
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  if(id_string !=''){
      id_string = id_string +','+id;
  }
  else{
      id_string = id;
  }

  status = 'Paid';
  } else {
  sum -= parseInt($(this).val());
  status = 'Not paid';
  }     
  $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).find('td:eq(2)').text(status);     
  $('#msg').text(sum);
  $('#bill_id').val(id_string);
      });
</script>
<form name=form1 action="GET">
    <table class='table table-striped' >
    <tr > <th >id</th><th >FEES name</th><th >status</th></tr>
    <tr ><td>1</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=100;> fee = 100 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=200 ;> fee = 200 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
    <tr  ><td>3</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=300;> fee = 300 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>
    <tr ><td>4</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=400 ;> fee = 400 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr>

    </table>
    <input type="text" name="bill_id" id="bill_id" value="">
    <input type="submit" >
    </form>

    <br>

    <div id=msg></div>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What does this code solve and how? A good answer should include a proper explanation.

Comment: Sorry i need to get the value of id of checked in the text box.not the sum in the,text box

Comment: But you have to assign id to the checkbox input first

Comment: i mean bill id which is a column name in the table

Comment: Ok, I have edit my answer, now its showing bill id in text box.

Comment: Pls note that i posted a snippet code so in that <script> tag is not needed. however, ur code is not working

Comment: You don't able to see the id's in textbox ? And can you please check your console if there is any error showing

Comment: But the problem is i want whole selected id to text box in ur code only current selected (single value is coming)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying `click` on body add `change` event to `input` with type `checkbox`. For ids, you can get the associated id of checked input using `$(this).parent().prev().text()`. Make an 
array of ids and when you submit join the ids array so as to get comma separated values.

```js
let sum = 0;
let ids = [];
const textInput = $('input[type="text"]');

$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    const isChecked = $(this)[0].checked;
    const val = parseInt($(this).val());
    const selectedId = parseInt($(this).parent().prev().text());

    if(isChecked) {
        sum = sum + val;
        ids.push(selectedId);
    } else {
        sum = sum - val;
        const index = ids.findIndex((id) =>id == selectedId);
        ids.splice(index, 1);
    }

    console.log("sum", sum);
    console.log('Ids', ids);
    
    textInput.val(ids.join(','));
});

$('input:submit').on('click', function() {
    if(ids.length > 0) { console.log(ids.join(','))}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='table table-striped' >
            <tr> 
                <th>id</th>
                <th>FEES name</th>
                <th>status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=100;> fee = 100 </td>
                <td>Not Paid</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=200 ;> fee = 200 </td><td>Not Paid</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- <tr  ><td>3</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=300;> fee = 300 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr> -->
            <!-- <tr ><td>4</td><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb class="due-fee" value=400 ;> fee = 400 </td><td>Not Paid</td></tr> -->
</table>
<input type="text" name="bill_id" id="bill_id">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: can u pls show how to put that ids value in the textbox?

Comment: @SharoonCk - See edit. use `$('input[type="text"]').val(ids.join(',')` or if you don't want comma, use space instead like `$('input[type="text"]').val(ids.join(' ')`